# How do I link a markdown file to the header using Hugo?

Tags: web, markdown, hugo

I'm using Hugo to build a static site, and I can't figure out how to link a markdown file to the header. For example, in this [website](https://hjdskes.github.io/), clicking the `About Me` section in the header is simply a rendering of the markdown file `content/about.md` (see the corresponding [git repo](https://github.com/Hjdskes/hjdskes.github.io/tree/hugo/content)).

So I know I have to have the markdown file in the `content` folder of my site, but I am using a different theme (the [Hugo Agency Theme](http://themes.gohugo.io/theme/agency/)), and I'd want, for example, the `About` section to link to a separate landing page, say `example.com/about`, just as it does in hjdskes's page.

I've been stuck on this for a while and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the theme lets you configure the menu URLs in the config.toml file.

For instance, I am using tranquilpeak on my Hugo site.  The config.toml file has a `[menu]` section letting me configure what the URL's are for each menu item.

If you put a about.md file in the root of the `content/` folder, it is accessed at `example.com/about`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.toml` you can find `[params.navigation]` section when you can configure the theme. The example `config.toml` you can find in [example site](https://github.com/digitalcraftsman/hugo-agency-theme/blob/master/exampleSite/config.toml#L46).

If you want to the `About` section to link to a separate landing page (ex. `example.com/about`), just

- comment `about = "About"` line
- add the new link to a separate page as follows:

  [[menu.postpend]]
  url = "http://example.com/about"
  name = "About"
  weight = 10

The `weight` param lets you set the position in the main menu.